# How to add a contributor (not collaborator) to a a private GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, pull-request

I have a free Github account with a private repository.

In the repository settings, there is an option to add an **collaborator** - who if I understand correctly, is someone who can push to my main branch.

What I'd really like to have is a **contributor** who can make a private pull request to my main branch (as I understand, pull requests of private repositories are also private).

So the question is, how can I give someone access to my private repository so that they can fork it and submit a pull request without making them a **collaborator**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, you have to have something other than a free account.

You could then set up [branch protection](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/) to prevent unauthorized collaborators from pushing to some of your branches.
To prevent them from pushing to *any branch*, you would then set the branch pattern to `*`.

If it is an option, you could use Gitlab which does have protected branches for free accounts (see [here](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/protected_branches)).

Comment: Thanks! In the case of GitLab, will the pull requests of the protected branches be private?

Comment: If the repository is private, all pull requests will be private (but all users that can see the repository can see the pull request). There is a proposal to have [confidential merge requests](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14567) which is scheduled to happen in the next releases (it is unclear how many).